# Monotouch ABAdressBook GetPhones Check For Null

Tags: c#, iphone, null, xamarin.ios, abaddressbook

```
ABAddressBook mybook = new ABAddressBook();
ABPerson[] allPeople =  mybook.GetPeople();
foreach(ABPerson thisPerson in allPeople){

      if(thisPerson.GetPhones() != null)
             ABMultiValue<string> myMultiPhone = thisPerson.GetPhones();

      }
}
```

I have the previous code in my application.  With Monotouch build 1.4 my application errors out. If there is no phone number associated with a contact, I get a null error.  Does anyone have any idea how to check for null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting the code in a try catch.  Oh well, it works.